# Why does trim() not remove the trailing white spaces in this example?

Tags: java, string, trim

I am revising Java from here: http://java-success.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/core-java-coding-questions-frequently.html and came along this question:

"Q1. What will be the output of the following code snippet?

```
String s = " Hello ";
s += " World ";
s.trim( );
System.out.println(s);
```

A1. The output will be

```
" Hello  World "
```

with the leading and trailing spaces. Some would expect a trimmed "Hello World".

So, what concepts does this question try to test?

String objects are immutable and there is a trick in s.trim( ) line.
Understanding object references and unreachable objects that are eligible for garbage collection."

Can someone explain why the trailing white spaces are not removed?

Comment: Just to help you in the future, here's how I would have worked to answer the question had I not known that s.trim() doesn't modify the string. In the question text, you are told `String objects are immutable and there is a trick in s.trim( ) line`. Since the only thing on that line is `s.trim( );`, I would look at what that does. Here's the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() The first line there tells you `Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.` Since the return value is ignored here, you've found your answer.

Answer (score 10):

The method `trim()` doesn't modify the `String`, which is immutable.  It returns the trimmed `String`, which is promptly ignored, leaving `s` unchanged.  Replace

```
s.trim( );
```

with

```
s = s.trim( );
```

Comment: Ah yes. I see it now. They deliberately missed out the assignment!